# android custom keyboardview is not working in Theme.Appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat, custom-keyboard, appcompatactivity

I had created a Custom Android Keyboard for my application when the theme was

> Theme.Holo.Light

But Recently i changed the theme to apply material design to the app and extended appcompatactivity to the java class file.

> Theme.Appcompat

& the keyboard does not give any output on the Edittext. When I change it back to the old theme it works again.
Here is my custom Key board

```
 <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Any Suggestions to make changes in the code.?
Thanks

Comment: I solved it on my own eventually had to pass the  `android.support.v7.widget.AppcombatEditText`  to the onkey press event of Custom Keyboard.